# Vectorize a for loop over a function?

Tags: r, for-loop, indexing, vectorization

I am trying to improve the runtime of a function (i.e. remove for loops) but this one is proving difficult for me. I need to apply my ema function over the range, and cant think of a way to vectorize this.

Is there a way to return the second function without a for loop?

```
ema<-function(v,n,a){     
  # v: a data vector
  # n: a scalar constant
  # a: a vector length v of contants
  expt<-c(0:(n-1))
  as<-c(1-a)
  avevec<-c(as^expt)
  sum(avevec*v)/sum(avevec) 
}
betaema<-function(v,n,a,l){ 
  # v: a data vector
  # n: a vector length v of contants
  # a: a vector length v of contants
  # l: a contant, the first value that can have a moving average
  secondvec<-c(rep(0, (length(v)-l)))
  for(i in l:(length(v)-l)){
    secondvec[i+1-l]<-ema(v[(i-n[i]+1):i],n[i],a[(i-n[i]+1):i])
  }
  secondvec
}
```

Comment: Where does `ema()` inside your function come from? It would also be nice if you could explain what you're trying to actually do with your new function.

Comment: Sorry about that, I added the ema function. The ema function is a moving average, and the betaema is the vector of moving averages, given a changing input.